# SQL Query with double nested level

Tags: mysql, sql, select, exists

I am doing the Stanford free online course (which I recommend!) and I am stuck at the following problem. Please help.

Find the names of all students who are friends with someone named Gabriel.

This is the best I could come up with.

```
select name 
from highschooler h 
where h.id exists in (
    select friend.id1 
    from friend 
    where friend.id2 exists in (
        select h.id 
        from highschooler h2 
        where h2.name="gabriel"
    )
);
```

I'm required to run the query in SQL Lite although I am using MySQL workbench as a test place (I have understood that they are relatively similar for basic queries like this one).

```
/* Create the schema for our tables */
create table Highschooler(ID int, name text, grade int);
create table Friend(ID1 int, ID2 int);
create table Likes(ID1 int, ID2 int);

/* Populate the tables with our data */
insert into Highschooler values (1510, 'Jordan', 9);
insert into Highschooler values (1689, 'Gabriel', 9);
insert into Highschooler values (1381, 'Tiffany', 9);
insert into Highschooler values (1709, 'Cassandra', 9);
insert into Highschooler values (1101, 'Haley', 10);
insert into Highschooler values (1782, 'Andrew', 10);
insert into Highschooler values (1468, 'Kris', 10);
insert into Highschooler values (1641, 'Brittany', 10);
insert into Highschooler values (1247, 'Alexis', 11);
insert into Highschooler values (1316, 'Austin', 11);
insert into Highschooler values (1911, 'Gabriel', 11);
insert into Highschooler values (1501, 'Jessica', 11);
insert into Highschooler values (1304, 'Jordan', 12);
insert into Highschooler values (1025, 'John', 12);
insert into Highschooler values (1934, 'Kyle', 12);
insert into Highschooler values (1661, 'Logan', 12);

insert into Friend values (1510, 1381);
insert into Friend values (1510, 1689);
insert into Friend values (1689, 1709);
insert into Friend values (1381, 1247);
insert into Friend values (1709, 1247);
insert into Friend values (1689, 1782);
insert into Friend values (1782, 1468);
insert into Friend values (1782, 1316);
insert into Friend values (1782, 1304);
insert into Friend values (1468, 1101);
insert into Friend values (1468, 1641);
insert into Friend values (1101, 1641);
insert into Friend values (1247, 1911);
insert into Friend values (1247, 1501);
insert into Friend values (1911, 1501);
insert into Friend values (1501, 1934);
insert into Friend values (1316, 1934);
insert into Friend values (1934, 1304);
insert into Friend values (1304, 1661);
insert into Friend values (1661, 1025);
insert into Friend select ID2, ID1 from Friend;

insert into Likes values(1689, 1709);
insert into Likes values(1709, 1689);
insert into Likes values(1782, 1709);
insert into Likes values(1911, 1247);
insert into Likes values(1247, 1468);
insert into Likes values(1641, 1468);
insert into Likes values(1316, 1304);
insert into Likes values(1501, 1934);
insert into Likes values(1934, 1501);
insert into Likes values(1025, 1101);
```

Any help hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to reference the Highschooler table twice for this, basically building the relationship Highschooler -> Friend -> Highschooler

Here's how to do it:

```
select h1.name
from Highschooler h1
inner join Friend f on f.ID1 = h1.ID
inner join Highschooler h2 on f.ID2 = h2.ID
where h2.name = 'Gabriel'
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6f01a/214/0) with the query above.

Comment: @Andrey I don't think we want distinct here. You can have multiple names in the table.

Answer (score 1):

What I recommend you do is break this down into pieces and put them back together.

First, let's get the IDs of all people who have the name gabriel:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM highschooler s
WHERE s.name = 'Gabriel';
```

Now, we can find the list of all friendships where this id exists as the id1:

```
SELECT f.id2
FROM friend f
WHERE f.id1 IN(SELECT s.id
                FROM highschooler s
                WHERE s.name = 'Gabriel');
```

Since you've set up the table to include both ways of listing the same two friends, you don't need to worry about doing the opposite (where f.id2 is Gabriel).

Now, you can join the above query with the highschooler table to get their name.

```
SELECT s.name
FROM highschooler s
JOIN(SELECT f.id2
    FROM friend f
    WHERE f.id1 IN(SELECT s.id
                    FROM highschooler s
                    WHERE s.name = 'Gabriel')
     ) t
ON t.id2 = s.id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d93f/6) example for.